# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role In Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I got struck here. There is a parent Table like below.

```
     class Parent{
        static hasMany = [child: Child];
        static Parent findByParent(Parent parent){
        def c = Parent.createCriteria()
        def result = c.get {
        child{
             idEq(parent.id)
        }
       }
      }
     }

    class Child {

    }
```

Below is controller action.

```
    def save(Child child){
      def orderList;
      if(parent){
        orderList = parent?.child(); // here i am getting exception. failed to lazily initialize 
                                      //  a collection of role: Parent.child, no session or session  
                                        //was closed. Stacktrace follows:
      }
    }
```

So how to handle this situation.Or is there any Annotations to Eager initialization.

Answer (score 4):

For eager fetching you can explicitly set lazy as false in your Parent domain .Try something like this

```
static mapping = {
    child lazy: false
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Am so glad it helped :).Request you to accept the answer as well :).

Comment: I think the issue with that is that it loads the whole collection when the container class is loaded